# Trying to move SKShapeNodes one at a time in a loop

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I want to move the nodes from an offscreen position and line them up across the X-axis spaced out. The nodes have been created and stored in an array. I have the following code to do it.  However, all of the nodes move at the same time.  I want them to move successively when the prior node is in its new position. I have tried altering the duration of the wait action, but it doesn't work.

Thanks

```
    var shapeNodes: [SKShapeNode] = [SKShapeNode]()
    let w = (size.width + size.height) * 0.05

    for _ in 1...5 {
        let s = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: w, height: w), cornerRadius: w * 0.3)
        s.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY + 75)
        s.zPosition = 3
        s.fillColor = UIColor.cyan
        shapeNodes.append(s)
        addChild(s)
    }

    var posX: CGFloat = 0.0
    for n in shapeNodes {
        let m = SKAction.moveBy(x: posX, y: -300, duration: 2.0)
        m.timingMode = .easeIn
        let w = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0)
        let seq = SKAction.sequence([ m, w ])
        n.run(seq)
        posX += 125
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give each node a wait action with a duration equal to the animation time of all previous nodes. The logic is very similar to your logic with the `posX` variable.

```
var posX: CGFloat = 0.0
var waitDuration: CGFloat = 0
for n in shapeNodes {
    let duration = 2
    let m = SKAction.moveBy(x: posX, y: -300, duration: duration)
    m.timingMode = .easeIn
    let w = SKAction.wait(forDuration: waitDuration)
    let seq = SKAction.sequence([w, m])
    n.run(seq)
    posX += 125
    waitDuration += duration
}
```

In the example above, I created another variable called `waitDuration`, which keeps track of the total time the node should wait before animating.

The duration of the wait action is set to the `waitDuration`, and at the end of the loop, I increase the `waitDuration` by the duration of the move action.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I wanted to do here.  Thank you for the education.